# Excel date insert to SQL Server table as 44381

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-logic-apps

I'm facing problem when Excel date column data were import SQL Server table through Logic apps.

Excel value shows as **7/4/2021** column. which was need import is a varchar column in the table. After data  import it shows as **44381**. Is there any solution for it.

Comment: *"which was need import is a varchar column in the table."* Why? `varchar` is not a one size fits all data type, and you should never store dates as a `varchar`. There are date and time data types for a reason, use them.

Comment: As for the answer, that's because `44381`, in Excel can be parsed as a date. Excel stores date and times as a numerical value in the background. 1 being 1900-01-01 or 13243.25 being 1936-04-04 06:00. As such 44381 would be your date 07 April 2021 or 04 July 2021 (didn't calculate which).

Comment: you are right I think it's because of  07 April 2021. Thank you for your feedback

Comment: @Haz Did you preview the data before run the pipeline? I tested load the same data from excel file to sql table varchar column, everything works well.

Comment: Hello @Haz, hope you're doing well. If my answer is helpful, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you preview the data before run the pipeline? I tested load the same data from excel file to SQL table varchar column, everything works well. We can't repeat you error.  Please check if there are any different steps between you and I.

This my source excel file:
[image]

Source dataset preview:
[image]

These three columns are both considered as String data type. My sink table schema and pipeline output:

[image]